# Force Tailwind to include some classes in build phase

Tags: css, angular, user-interface, tailwind-css

in my Angular project, I recently moved a menu from a typescript variable to a dynamically loaded json from backend.

Some Tailwind classes were used only in this menu so now at build time Tailwind doesn't know that it has to include styles for those classes.

Is it possible to force Tailwind to always include some classes? For example by working on the tailwind.config.js file.

As workaround, actually I've included this row in my index.html (but i don't like the errors from eslint):

```
<!--<span class="hidden bg-green-400 bg-pink-400"></span>-->
```

Comment: You may pecify `safelist` array within config file (like [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes)) or add safelist.txt file with classes and add it into `content` key of a config

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka how do you add a txt file to tailwind css config?

Comment: @Daniel same way as you include any other file - within `content` section of configuration file, like `./safelist.txt` or anything you wish

Answer (score 79, accepted):

As suggested by Ihar Aliakseyenka, the "safelist" section is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Ihar!

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{html,js}'
    './components/**/*.{html,js}',
  ],
  safelist: [
    'bg-red-500',
    'text-3xl',
    'lg:text-4xl',
  ]
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 23):

`Tailwind` uses `tree-shaking` i.e any class that wasn't declared in your source files, won't be generated in the output file.

Hence use [`safelist classes`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) .

In `tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{html,js}',
    './components/**/*.{html,js}',
  ],
  safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /bg-(red|green|blue|orange)-(100|500|700)/, // You can display all the colors that you need
      variants: ['lg', 'hover', 'focus', 'lg:hover'],      // Optional
    },
  ],
  // ...
}
```

---

##### How to make it more generic to include all possible tailwind colors?

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
     ...
  ],
  safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /bg-+/, //   This includes bg of all colors and shades
    },
  ],
  ...
}
```