# Tailwind and vue v-html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, vue-composition-api

I have a vue component that takes a prop of raw html, the HTML comes from a wysiwyg which uses tailwind classes to do the styling just like our vue app.

However when doing `v-html="responseFromAPI"` in my component the rawHTML remains unstyled due to tailwind and how it renders I am guessing. Is there a way I can get the response from api into a component and rendered correctly?

Comment: You can insert an element as the firstchild of your component with `class='hidden other-classes-you-want'`. `v-html` will replace the content anyway, so I guess tailwind will encounter the classes you need at build time and  your fetched component will render correctly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force Tailwind to include some classes in build phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71186718/force-tailwind-to-include-some-classes-in-build-phase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tailwind runs at **build** time to generate the CSS class rules. Your `v-html="responseFromAPI"` would run at **runtime**. By this time, Tailwind is already inert and done its job and is no longer part of the app.

To work around this, you could look at configuring a [`safelist`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) of classes that are used in the raw html response.